# How do I make a parallax background image of a div resposive

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have a div on the top of the page that is assigned a parallax image, when the view port is not that wide the image is not responsive, how can I make the background image responsive ?

```css
#parallax{
    height:100vh;
    background:url("../images/keyboard.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
    <div id="parallax">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div id="profile" class="bottom-align col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

and here are the screenshots of what I mean by unresponsive 
[image]

[image]

basically I want "web site" to show when the view port is not wide as well instead of "WE"

Comment: try `width: 100%`

Comment: i did , if u mean in #parallaxDiv it didnt work :/

Comment: To the actual image tag. Would be nice to see a working example for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have your image width be 100%. I put the image tags inside the divs to represent screen sizes.

```html
<div style="width:20%">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Triforce.svg/691px-Triforce.svg.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div style="width:40%">    
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Triforce.svg/691px-Triforce.svg.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div style="width:60%">    
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Triforce.svg/691px-Triforce.svg.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div style="width:80%">    
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Triforce.svg/691px-Triforce.svg.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
<div style="width:100%">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/Triforce.svg/691px-Triforce.svg.png" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover` is scaling your background image to fill the whole height of the containing element which on a mobile device is tall and narrow, cropping the image.

You should either use `background-size: contain` instead of `cover`, or allow the containing element to shrink to less than 100vh. The caveat with the former is you need to figure out what to fill the rest of the container with.

Here's an example:

```css
.target {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/100);
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: teal;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
}
.better {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/300/100);
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: teal;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Cover:
  <br>
  <div class="target"></div>

  Contain:
  <br>
  <div class="better"></div>

  <div>
    Original:
    <br>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/100" ?>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution would be :

- Make your body size stretch to the whole view-port

  `body{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
   /* on the example due to some overflow I've used 97% to prevent scroll bars`

  ....
- make your background image fill the body element

  `background-image:url(...);
  background-position:cover;`

And that's it,

- To live a white space for your header offset your image position down, by the width of your header.

  `background-position:50px;`

The inconvenience is when you want to have actual content you can't rely on the same style sheet for the other pages, you have to change it.

Of course you won't see any responsiveness in the example here because the way the snippet is in a fixed width container. But it has work as expected when tested. (at least you can see how the image is stretched compared to [the original one here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWVa6.jpg) )

```css
.header{
 border:solid ;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

body{
  width:97%;
  height:97%;

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWVa6.jpg);
  background-position:0 50px;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">your header or navigation bar</div>
```